# Django Login Form Returning false on is_valid() if username already exists

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a login form I created from Django's `User` model:

**forms.py**:

```
class LoginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '@username'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'})
        }
```

**views.py**:

```
    reg = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if reg.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse('Success: valid form')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Error: invalid form')
```

Now if I try login in with a *username* that is not registered it returns **Success: valid form** but if it is a 
username that already exists, it says **Error: invalid form**.

I tried doing this in command line and below is what I get (I first tried it with a username that is register, **yax**):

```
In [2]: data = {'username':'yax', 'password':'wrong_password'}
In [3]: form = LoginForm(data)

In [4]: form.is_valid()
Out[5]: False
In [6]: form.errors
Out[7]: {'username': [u'A user with that username already exists.']}

In [8]: data = {'username':'wrong_name', 'password':'wrong_password'}
In [9]: form = LoginForm(data)

In [10]: form.is_valid()
Out[11]: True
In [12]: form.errors
Out[13]: {}
```

Would be glad I can know why I am getting this error and how do I solve it.

Comment: show us your error.print out `print(req.errors)`

Answer (score 2):

A login form should not be a ModelForm. That's for creating or editing model instances - in this case, since you don't supply an `instance` parameter, Django assumes you want to create a new user.

Just use a standard Form and define the username and password fields explicitly.

Alternatively, use the [AuthenticationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) supplied in django.contrib.auth.forms, wich takes care of the entire authentication/login process for you.

Comment: I tried `loginForm = AuthenticationForm()` and then `reg = AuthenticationForm(request.POST or None)` when `request.method == 'POST'` but I still get the same error.

Comment: What, you're still getting "A user with that username already exists" from AuthenticationForm?

Comment: I am not getting that error. I get an empty error (no error) when I `return HttpResponse('reg.errors')`. But I also tried `return HttpResponse('request.POST')` but I only see dict keys, `usernamecsrfmiddlewaretokenpasswordregister`, without any data. My form submits to its view which is `def index(request): #codes`.

Comment: I can't understand why you would return any of those things; they are just literal strings. But you should show your view and your template.

Answer (score 1):

code for login view function(hope it will help someone):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import LoginForm


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```