# Django custom user not able to log in from web app but works fine in Admin

Tags: django, authentication, django-custom-user

I have created an App called "myapp" with custom user called "CustomUser" along with a custom user app called "customuser". I am able to successfully login from the admin. But I am not able to login from the app login.

Here is the login function:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get("password")

        user = authenticate(request,email=email,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,'You are logged in')
        else:
            
            messages.error(request,"invalid login credentials")
            return redirect(login)
           
        return redirect(request,'myapp/home.html')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'customuser/login.html', {'form':form})
```

Here is the admin:

```
from customuser.forms import *
from customuser.models import Profiles
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    filter_horizontal=()
    list_display = ('email', 'FirstName','LastName', 'last_login','is_active','date_joined','is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin','is_staff')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'description': (
                "Enter the new user's name and email address and click save."
                " The user will be emailed a link allowing them to login to"
                " the site and set their password."
            ),
            'fields': ('email', )}),
            ('Password', {
            'description': "Optionally, you may set the user's password here.",
            'fields': ('password',),
            'classes': ('collapse', 'collapse-closed'),
        }),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('FirstName','LastName')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin','is_staff')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email',  'password',  'FirstName','LastName', 'is_admin'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('email','FirstName','LastName')
    ordering = ('email','FirstName','LastName')
    filter_horizontal = ()
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change and (not form.cleaned_data['password'] or not obj.has_usable_password()):
            
            obj.set_password(get_random_string())
            reset_password = True
        else:
            reset_password = False

        super(UserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        if reset_password:
            reset_form = PasswordResetForm({'email': obj.email})
            assert reset_form.is_valid()
            reset_form.save(
                request=request,
                use_https=request.is_secure(),
                subject_template_name='registration/account_creation_subject.txt',
                email_template_name='registration/account_creation_email.html',
            )

admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)

admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

It looks like the login function is not resulting in user object.

Comment: Just covering bases.  You've got a line in your views.py (where your login view lives) doing something like: from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login?

Comment: Good question yes! Here is what I am importing from .auth. "from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login as auth_login"

Comment: Next question, because I can't see much wrong with your code. Can you confirm the users you are trying to login are active (eg the is_active flag in your admin is set for them)?

Comment: Yes the user is active and successfully log in through the admin. Also as an additional detail  when I am trying login through customaccounts/login I get an "invalid credentials" message. Basically it's executing the else part of the the user authenticated conditional logic. Something about my 'user = authenticate(request,email=email,password=password)' is not working right.

Comment: Post.get() will return none if a value fails, rather than erroring, which may be hiding the problem. Check the name values in your form.  Make sure they match the case and text of the field, eg, you haven't set <input name="Email"> or name="Password".  If that's not it, can you include the form code to have a closer look at?

Comment: It turns out the form was actually not valid and that was not showing because I didn't have the "if form.is_valid() condition. Reason for invalid form was because I used modelForm for my authentication form attaching it to the CustomUser Model. The answer in this post helped; [Django Login Form Returning false on is_valid() if username already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615504/django-login-form-returning-false-on-is-valid-if-username-already-exists). Solution was creating a new form that doesn't inherit from Django AuthnticationForm and doesn't use ModelForm.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end.  I should have thought to test for validity,  I guess sometimes things become invisible through familiarity.  There's a lesson in that for all of us :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was creating a new form that doesn't inherit from base Django AuthenticationForm and not using ModelForm.